# JavaFx: jfxTextField with icons

Tags: javafx

Hi I'm not able to add an icon to my jfxtextfield and found nothing about
could anyone help?

fxml:

```
<VBox fx:id="root" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <HBox fx:id="boxLogo" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="300.0">
         <children>
            <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="HOME" size="50">
               <fill>
                  <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0" startY="0.49047619047619045">
                     <stops>
                        <Stop color="#0d96ff" />
                        <Stop color="#010f1b" offset="1.0" />
                     </stops>
                  </LinearGradient>
               </fill>
            </FontAwesomeIconView>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <GridPane fx:id="boxField" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="222.0" prefWidth="300.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="131.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="108.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="142.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="107.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="142.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="107.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <JFXTextField fx:id="userTxt" alignment="CENTER" focusColor="#1cffb3" labelFloat="true" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="200.0" text="Digite o seu Login" unFocusColor="#00fffb" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" />
            <JFXTextField alignment="CENTER" focusColor="#00ff77" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="200.0" text="Digite a sua senha" unFocusColor="#00fffb" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <JFXCheckBox text="Lembrar Usuario" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="50.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </JFXCheckBox>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <HBox fx:id="boxButtons" alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="30.0">
         <children>
            <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="86.0" ripplerFill="#09fff7" style="-fx-background-color: #0DA5E2;" text="Entrar" textFill="WHITE" textOverrun="CLIP">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXButton>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

my controller:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private VBox root;

    @FXML
    private HBox boxLogo;

    @FXML
    private GridPane boxField;

    @FXML
    private HBox boxButtons;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField userTxt;

    public void initialize() {
        FontAwesomeIconView icon = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.USER);


    }
}
```

I wanted to add the icon I created to my textfiedl userTxt
I don't know if this can be done by controller or just by css?

From what I found is through css, but I would need to add a folder with a photo to work I wanted to do that with an icon is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to add this in your controller :

```
myJFXTextField.setstyle("-fx-background 
image:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rockettheme/halloween/32/pumpkin- 
icon.png');");
```

and this in your css

```
.text-field {
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -fx-background-position: right center;
  -fx-font-size: 20;
}
```

You can use a path or URL